# How to expand FAT32 SD Card Image

Tags: partition, parted

Given sd_card.img that is 512000000 bytes (i.e. 488MB):

$ `file sd_card.img`

> sd_card.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xc, start-CHS (0x0,1,1), end-CHS (0xdf,15,54), startsector 63, 999873 sectors, extended partition table (last)

`fdisk` shows:

```
Selected partition 1
         Device: sd_card.img1
          Start: 63
            End: 999935
        Sectors: 999873
      Cylinders: 1158
           Size: 488.2M
             Id: c
           Type: W95 FAT32 (LBA)
    Start-C/H/S: 0/1/1
      End-C/H/S: 223/15/54
```

I attempted to resize it with the following commands.

$ `cp sd_card.img test.img`

$ `dd if=/dev/zero of=test_zeros bs=1 count=1 seek=2G`

$ `cat test_zeros >> test.img`

$ `sudo parted test.img resizepart 1 2.5GB`

$ `file test.img`

> test.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xc, start-CHS (0x0,1,1), end-CHS (0x12f,239,61), startsector 63, 4882750 sectors

`fdisk` shows:

```
Selected partition 1
         Device: test.img1
          Start: 63
            End: 4882812
        Sectors: 4882750
      Cylinders: 334
           Size: 2.3G
             Id: c
           Type: W95 FAT32 (LBA)
    Start-C/H/S: 0/1/1
      End-C/H/S: 303/239/61
```

Then I write the image to the 32GB SD card:

```
dd if=test.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 conv=fsync status=progress
```

When the SD card is mounted...

`# lsblk`

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
`-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  2.3G  0 part /run/media/mmcblk0p1
```

This looks promising, but `df -h` is not so much.  This is what it shows with the original sd_card.img written to the SD card and after this modification:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p1  485M  159M  326M  33% /run/media/mmcblk0p1
```

Since `lsblk` displays block device size and `df` displays filesystem size, it suggests something is wrong with the partition.

Unfortunately, easier methods do not work well with FAT32 partitions, which I am limited to.  After installing necessary libraries, I tried `sudo gparted sd_card.img` but it did not work, various operations instead showing **sd_card.img1** and stating the file did not exist.

Any suggestions on what the issue in my procedure might be or otherwise how to do this properly?

Note:  GNU Parted 3.4

## Update

Following @eyoung100's suggestion, I wrote my original sd_card.img to the SD card and then used the command line tool `parted`, which is installed with GParted, in an attempt to expand the free space.

`sudo parted`

`select /dev/mmcblk0`

`print free`

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  512MB   512MB   primary  fat32        lba
        512MB   31.9GB  31.4GB           Free Space
```

`resizepart 1 100%`

`print free`

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  31.9GB  31.9GB  primary  fat32        lba
```

`quit`

Because GParted does not do anything until it is told to Apply changes, I wonder about quitting without saving anything, but when I boot from the SD card the changes are displayed so I think `parted` is more of a "gloves off" version where you really need to know what you are doing.

`# df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p1  485M  172M  313M  36% /run/media/mmcblk0p1
```

`# lsblk`

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
`-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0 29.7G  0 part /run/media/mmcblk0p1
```

So as previously mentioned, the changes I make in `parted` are actualized, but they are not found in usable space or the output of `df -h`.  The actual size of the FAT32 partition remains ~488MB.

`# fdisk -x /dev/mmcblk0`

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.72 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe847ab93

Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors Id Type            Start-C/H/S   End-C/H/S Attrs
/dev/mmcblk0p1         63 62333951 62333889  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)       0/1/1 1023/254/63
```

When this sd_card.img is inserted into another device to boot of off, it gets mounted by that device.  I am not sure how yet, but I see this>

`# cat /run/systemd/transient/run-media-mmcblk0p1.mount`

```
# This is a transient unit file, created programmatically via the systemd API. Do not edit.
[Unit]
After=dev-mmcblk0p1.device
BindsTo=dev-mmcblk0p1.device

[Mount]
What=/dev/mmcblk0p1
Options=umask=007,gid=6

[Unit]
Requires=systemd-fsck@dev-mmcblk0p1.service
After=systemd-fsck@dev-mmcblk0p1.service
```

Comment: GParted does not work on individual files (that I know of).  Try just `gparted` then input your sudo password and let gparted determine the available devices and complete your task.

Comment: @eyoung100 when I open gparted it shows me the hard drive in the graphical view and provides options.  With `gparted sd_card.img` it shows me the graphical view of my .img file with accurate information.

Comment: Well, I learned something new.  Thanks!  When the SD Card is mounted, and you open with just `gparted` can you see your SD card in the device list on the top left?

Comment: Yes, it is the only device listed.  And it displays as expected for sd_card.img and test.img, with test.img showing 2.33GiB size and 152.1MiB unallocated after the first partition.

Comment: And what happens when you click the partition you want resized and attempt to resize it? Do you have an ! next to that partition? As a hunch, you can't resize a partition if: 1) It's currently mounted, or 2) The SD card is in a size adapter. The adapters mark the card as read-only.  In this case, a screenshot would be warranted.

Comment: For temp.img it does let me move the slider, which reduces the "free space following" if to the right.  On the original sd_card.img, there was no free space following the FAT32 partition so it would not let me modify it.

Comment: Though when I go back to sd_card.img, add on the "free space" with the `cat...` command, open that new gparted.img with `sudo gparted gparted.img` and resize it to take up all of the free space it fails.  The error is that "fsck.fat -a -w -v '~/gparted.img1' fails with "open: No such file or directory"

Comment: You cannot resize the original image.  The original image is going to always be 500 MB's  You can only resize the Test Image because that's Bigger than the original 500.  You CANNOT `dd` the bigger image back to the smaller device because the smaller device is physically smaller.   It would be like trying to park 3 cars in a 2 car garage(The free space you're adding is like the 3rd car. You can't add "free space").  Using `gparted`, copy the 500MB Partition to the 32GB SDCard, and then expand it AFTER COPYING it to fill the entire 32GB.  Do you need that written as an answer?

Comment: I did not try to resize the original image or `dd` the larger to a smaller size.  And you may be surprised to find that your solution did not work, though it was interesting to try.  It seemed that `resizepart` in `parted` for /dev/mmcblk0 did work, after I wrote sd_card.img to the SD card, and 'print' showed that it had been resized...but when it is mounted, it still shows the original 488MB like described in my question.

Comment: GPaarted is just a Graphical Frontend to `parted`.  It contains all the tools `parted` uses like `resizepart`.  Please see my answer and let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to unconfuse us both, I'm now writing this as an answer.

### Confusion

You either have the original image still mounted when you finish, or you have improperly resized the original image.

### Starting Fresh

1. Unmount all your SD Cards.
2. Follow this [command line tutorial](https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/writing-sd-card-image-linux-command-line/), or use this [tool/Etcher](https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/getting-started/#step-2-flash-the-sd-card) linked from that tutorial to write the small 500 MB image file to your Bigger 32GB SD Card or other device.

**Note**: *Even though the tutorial above was written for a Pi based OS, the instructions apply for all SD Cards.  Also note that I'm not rewriting the commands contained there, so confusion is minimized.*

3. You should now have an extracted image file of 488MB written to a 32GB card, leaving about 31.5 GB

If I'm understanding correctly, you (the OP) would like to expand the partition so that it fills the entire 32 GB

### Expanding the Partition

1. We no longer need to worry about creating a second image because we wrote the original small image to the bigger SD Card in step 2 above.
2. Start GParted.
3. Remove and Reinsert the 32GB SD Card, so that GParted rescans the device nodes and refreshes.
4. You should see the small 500GB Partition on the SD Card surrounded by a teal colored box on the left side of the bar, and a whole bunch of Gray on the right with the words `Free Space`.
5. Drag the Arrow at the end of the teal box all the way to the end of the Free Space (as far right as you can).
6. Press the Checkmark in the Toolbar to Apply/Save the change.

---

Let me know if this is what you wanted to achieve.  If not, you need to provide more clarity or detail in your question.

Comment: A main point of divergence is that the only Linux machine I can insert an SD card into is headless so I can only `ssh` into it and I am not looking to set up an x11 session of some sort.  That is why my question and responses all involve `parted`, rather than GParted.  
But `parted` is part of GParted so the same operations should work.  I updated my question with details on how following your steps went.  As mentioned previously, it is for some reason not working as expected.

Comment: @fm_user8 gparted is a software on its own, not merely a frontend to parted. `parted` no longer resizes filesystems; `resizepart` merely resizes the partition. you can either use a very old version of parted that still resizes fat32 on its own (`resize` command instead of `resizepart`); or try a different tool like `fatresize`.

Comment: Knowing it is headless does help.  After the partition table looks the way you want `resizepart1 100%` is correct, along with `quit` which  should save the changes.  Did you receive any status message from `parted` about updating `fstab`?  See [here](https://medium.com/@doh_88292/learn-how-to-use-the-parted-command-to-partition-storage-devices-in-linux-a469eb903c9c)

Comment: @eyoung100 yes, it does mention updating fstab, but this SD card is used to boot another device so the local fstab would not apply.  After booting the other device, that device mounts the SD card, so maybe something on that device needs to be changed in some fashion, though from what I have seen it is automounted so the size seems to be set automatically.  `mount` on that device shows: 
 `/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /run/media/mmcblk0p1 type vfat (rw,relatime,gid=6,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)`

Comment: Older versions of `parted` do not support `fs.type=vfat`.  Try `type fat32`

Comment: @frostschutz thank you for the suggestion, but I get various errors with fatresize.  It says it cannot detect the filesystem of my original sd_card.img, will not resize it because it is "outside of the device ~/sd_card.img" and when I try `cp sd_card.img fatresize.img && cat test_zeros >> fatresize.img && fatresize fatresize.img -s 2500M` is fails from `Assertion (disk != NULL) at libparted/disk.c:1620`

Comment: You misunderstood: edit the `/etc/fstab` of the system that needs booting.  See if you get an error when it mounts as type `fat32`instead of `vfat`